# Adding image and other elements in responsive manner using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put few html elements in particular way. But as first I added image, it's size is not getting changed.

I added `.img-rounded1 { float:left; height:60% !important ; width:30% !important}` to change the image proprty.

also tried with `float:left; height:60% !important ; width:30% !important` inline inside image tag. But no help.

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/dZTh6/2/

I want to display elements like this:

[image]

What layout shoult I use for this inside `content1` div? Should I take table with 4 column or any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I undestood you.

If you want to make the image the same width as it parent, you have to add img-responsive (which will use max-width: 100%;):

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/931x754"  alt="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded">
```

The previous solution will make a "column type" layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/dZTh6/6/

Also you can do layouts using combinations of columns and rows.

But you have to think about floating the image inside its container so the "text" (or whatever is gonna surround it fill the space). , and floating the image inside the container.

If you want to do a column layout for the first content and a row one for the second, check this code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dZTh6/5/

May you want to remove padding given by col-xs-* class.

Comment: `img-container1 { float:left; height:60% !important; width:40%}` here changing height why does not reflect?

Comment: You have to set height: 100%; on the parent element in order to do that. Notice that then the height in percent will refers to the width of the parent container.

Comment: thanks, can you please help, just by adding single text box and label in parallel to image?

Comment: Sure, but can you tell me what do you mean with lavel ? And also, in which of the two examples you want it. Thanks !

Comment: sorry it was label, which way is better and starndard here? I guess using row and column is standard way, right? http://jsfiddle.net/dZTh6/5/

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with label, but anyway, here is another example http://jsfiddle.net/dZTh6/8/ Add to another container what you want (label?) and then play with margins, etc... in order to make a better layout. Hope it helps !

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted